# ASP MVC Validate time

Tags: validation

I am trying to create a custom data annotations time validator to validate a datetime time field.  I would like it to validate on the client.
I found an example to follow on this site but I think part of it is missing.
I do believe that the class I created is partially working because it seems to be validating newly created entries but does not validate when in Edit.
Also
    I am using a timepicker with  jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js.

```
I also have added this to my web.config 
 <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
<add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
```

And I have added jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js" to the timepicker bundle I created.
Below you will find bits of my model, the TimeAttribute class I created and my Edit cshtml.
Any help is much appreciated

```
    [DisplayName("Injury Time")]
    [DataType(DataType.Time)]
    [Time]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:hh:mm tt}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> InjuryTime { get; set; }
```

`
public class TimeAttribute : ValidationAttribute, IClientValidatable
{
    public IEnumerable GetClientValidationRules(ModelMetadata metadata, ControllerContext context)
    {
        yield return new ModelClientValidationRule
        {
            ErrorMessage = ErrorMessage,
            ValidationType = "time"
        };
    }

```
public override bool IsValid(object value)
{
    DateTime time;
    if (value == null || !DateTime.TryParse(value.ToString(), out time))
        return false;

    return true;
}
```

}
`
 
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.InjuryTime, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.InjuryTime)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.InjuryTime)

Answer (score 0):

Keep it simple. Use [Remote] validation attribute instead that you has created.

There's a example:

**Model:**

```
[DisplayName("Injury Time")]
[DataType(DataType.Time)]
[Remote("CheckTime", "Home", ErrorMessage = "Please check this field")]
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:hh:mm tt}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
public Nullable<System.DateTime> InjuryTime { get; set; }
```

Where *Home* is your controller.

**Controller:**

```
public ActionResult CheckTime(Nullable<System.DateTime> InjuryTime)
        {
            if (InjuryTime == something)
            {
        // This show the error message of validation
                return Json(true, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
            else
            {
        // This will ignore the validation
               return Json(false, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
        }
```

As simple like that. No modifications must to be done on the view.
Feel free to ask.